# Internal differences between CPUs of the same architecture

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, x86

What is the difference between, for example an Intel i3-4005U (1.7 GHz) and an Intel i3-4025U (1.9 GHz)? These CPUs are from the same generation, have the same amount of cores, cache, iGPU, and supported features with the only difference being the clock speed.

Would these CPUs internally be identical except for the clock circuit? Or would the faster one have internal improvements to allow it to run at the higher clock speed?

Comment: Binning is a thing. Even if the two CPUs have different cores and cache. No point throwing away a 50% or 75% good product or slightly underperforming but otherwise functional product.

Comment: According to [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=81019,75105), both processors have almost the same functionality, except for the clock speed and a feature called "Intel® Smart Response Technology".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there are no internal differences aside from what clock speeds the firmware allows them to run.  Within a given architecture Intel does actually make physically different CPUs though.  In this case since you have a Haswell CPU, see:

https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/haswell_(client)#Die

Typically Intel has about 3 or 4 consumer dies split between mobile and desktop and another 3 server dies.  Since taping out and then manufacturing a new die is expensive, they try and make all models they sell each generation from those 6 or 7 different dies.  This also allows them to bin lower yielding dies into cheaper products.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I was not aware of this, it's very interesting.